# Update Operation in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I want to update one column in LINQ to SQL. My Query is like :-

```
private void UpdateCourse()
{
      OperationDataContext OdContext = new OperationDataContext();
      //Get Single course which need to update
      COURSE objCourse = OdContext.COURSEs.Single(course => course.course_name == "B.Tech");
      //Field which will be update
      objCourse.course_desc = "Bachelor of Technology";
      // executes the appropriate commands to implement the changes to the database
      OdContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

My question is first it take record from COURSEs which match the criteria Than it update it. It this right approach? or SP is right solution here.

Suggest!

Comment: This may help you :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/358445/Most-efficient-way-to-update-with-LINQ-to-SQL

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter.  Either way will work.  if you are asking which is more efficient, stored procedures are generally more efficient, but the update above works just fine, and keeps all of the update logic within the application code.

As far as what gets updated, run SQL profiler, and you'll see how LINQ crafts the update statement against the database, and weigh the options yourself.

Comment: Yes both will work fine. But which one is fast and efficient? Suppose i have 15 column in table all are varchar(max) than LINQ TO SQL first fetch all column and than update means 2 hit to DB. Which one(above mention way OR Stored procedure) is fast and preferred?

Comment: LIke I had said, stored procedures will always be more efficient... the question is how inefficient will LINQ be.  For what you are trying to do, to update one record with many text fields, stored procedure will always be faster, but LINQ read/update shouldn't be that inefficient...